# Having problems with loading datasets - images

Tags: python, arrays, keras, dataset

I'm trying to build a model for plant disease detection using Keras, but I seem to have this error when I tried load my datasets and convert it to an array. The image appears in the error doesn't exist in my datasets, I have no idea why.

```py
EPOCHS = 25
INIT_LR = 1e-3
BS = 32
default_image_size = tuple((256, 256))
image_size = 0
directory_root = "C:\\Users\\vipek\\Desktop\\PlantVillage-Dataset\\raw\\color"
width=256
height=256
depth=3

image_list, label_list = [], []

try:
    print("[INFO] Loading images ...")
    root_dir = listdir(directory_root)
    for directory in root_dir :
        # remove .DS_Store from list
        if directory == ".DS_Store" :
            root_dir.remove(directory)

    for plant_folder in root_dir :
        plant_disease_folder_list = listdir(f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}")
        
        for disease_folder in plant_disease_folder_list :
            # remove .DS_Store from list
            if disease_folder == ".DS_Store" :
                plant_disease_folder_list.remove(disease_folder)

        for plant_disease_folder in plant_disease_folder_list:
            print(f"[INFO] Processing {plant_disease_folder} ...")
            plant_disease_image_list = listdir(f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}/{plant_disease_folder}/")
                
            for single_plant_disease_image in plant_disease_image_list :
                if single_plant_disease_image == ".DS_Store" :
                    plant_disease_image_list.remove(single_plant_disease_image)

            for image in plant_disease_image_list[:500]:
                image_directory = f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}/{plant_disease_folder}/{image}"
                if image_directory.endswith(".jpg") == True or image_directory.endswith(".JPG") == True:
                    image_list.append(convert_image_to_array(image_directory))
                    label_list.append(plant_disease_folder)
    print("[INFO] Image loading completed")  
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error : {e}")
```

This is the output i got:

> [INFO] Loading images ...
>
> [INFO] Processing 00416648-be6e-4bd4-bc8d-82f43f8a7240___GCREC_Bact.Sp 3110.JPG ...
>
> Error : [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\Users\vipek\Desktop\PlantVillage-Dataset\raw\color/Tomato___Bacterial_spot/00416648-be6e-4bd4-bc8d-82f43f8a7240___GCREC_Bact.Sp 3110.JPG/'

Comment: you have a slash at the end of your image path (before filename)

Answer (score 2):

Were you able to load any images at all? I think you get the error because your directory is invalid, meaning your root is defined `C:\something\something` and then at some point you switch to `folder/folder/folder`. You need to use backslashes only. Also I'm pretty sure your code adds `/` after specifying the file type (JPG). That shouldn't be there.

Hope that helps.

Comment: how do i switch back to "\"?

Comment: Instead of having this when you define a directory `plant_disease_image_list = listdir(f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}/{plant_disease_folder}/") ` change it to  `plant_disease_image_list = listdir(f"{directory_root}\{plant_folder}\{plant_disease_folder}")` . You see, all the " \ "-s go in the same direction. In case that doesn't work, use the `/` everywhere but you have to be consistent. The problem is that you have defined your root directory with "\ "-s and then when you expand it to the sub-folders you suddenly switch to "/ ". This way the path becomes unrecognizable as a directory.

Comment: I changed it, but it still shows the same error, but with "/" this time.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the space in `00416648-be6e-4bd4-bc8d-82f43f8a7240___GCREC_Bact.Sp 3110.JPG` is causing this error

Comment: how do i eliminate that?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the `Path` Python 3 library to deal with paths. My guess is that the path is not being recognized correctly. Based on the `Path` library I would change a couple of lines in your code, qhere paths are being defined:

```
# header
from pathlib import Path

# ...

directory_root = Path("C:\\Users\\vipek\\Desktop\\PlantVillage-Dataset\\raw\\color")

# ...

plant_disease_folder_list = listdir(directory_root / plant_folder)

# ...

plant_disease_image_list = listdir(directory_root / plant_folder / plant_disease_folder)
```

And make sure you avoid the last '/' in the `plant_disease_image_list` path!

Comment: I did the changes, but i got another error: 

[INFO] Loading images ...
Error : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str'

Comment: My bad! You should use everywhere the / operator instead of +

Comment: I did the changes, i still got the same error, but instead of "+", it shows "/" this time

Comment: could you tell me the line? is it the `plant_disease_folder_list`?

Comment: this is the error: 
[INFO] Loading images ...
Error : unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'